# Sending custom GET requests in Wordpress as clean url's

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have a page called "user" and on that page I show stats about specyfic user,but the url is like http://somepage.com/user/?u=ID , I want to make http://somepage.com/user/ID , tried htaccess, but no result

Comment: Please post the rewrite rules you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I would've said htaccess but you say no result?

Are you sure you did it right?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^user/([.]+)$ user/?u=$1
```

or something like that.

Sorry if I'm teaching to suck eggs, but at least you can tick it off with someone else giving you the same thing you've tried :)

edit:

OK you've tried that. Now I'm guessing we're looking at this the wrong way?

RewriteRule ^user/?u=([.]+)$ User/$1

I'm not sure if wordpress will understand this though.

Comment: I did that in the first place :/

Comment: Hmm I think I get your issue. Since word press already goes to a location... right-ho...

Answer (score 0):

Or just use google and the first result is...

[http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/clean-url’s-with-wordpress](http://teamtutorials.com/web-development-tutorials/clean-url%E2%80%99s-with-wordpress)

Comment: and don't forget voting up and selecting the answer that works for you mate. I looked at your profile and you've not accepted one answer... doing that will make people not want to answer your questions in future :)

Comment: cause that where not the anwsers I was looking for :/ 
the problem is still unsolved, my only option is to use 404 template to show user stats,but that will be not good

Comment: How is it not? Have you read that link? You asked for the wordpress neat links, that site gives clean urls, what issues do you still get? Any errors? Are you confused at any point. You need to give more info!